# which is the template or theme of librosweb.es?

Tags: wordpress, templates, joomla, themes

I would like to know which is the template or theme of this website librosweb.es I guess they use some CMS with some templeate but they are hidden.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only confirm that it isn't Joomla or Wordpress from looking at the code. The tidiness of the code suggests to me that it is likely to be a bespoke system or a static site - most CMS systems leave their footprints in the code somewhere.

The html/css is using Bootstrap.

None of the online "what CMS is this?" sites recognise it, which again suggests it isn't a well-known CMS.